Q. 25 from A first course in probability by Sheldon Ross 10 ed.
In each round, an archer shoots two arrows at a target that has an outer ring(O), an inner ring(I), and a bullseye(B). The archer will stop shooting once she hits bullseye twice(BB), or the inner ring twice(II), or the bullseye and the inner ring once each. The probabilities of hitting the inner ring and the bullseye are .5 and .1 respectively.
(a) What is the probability she will never stop shooting?
(b) What is the probability she will stop shooting for having hit bullseye twice?
Solution I thought
$P(B)^2 = 0.01$
$P(I)P(B) = 0.05$
$P(B)P(I) = 0.05$
$P(I)^2 = 0.25$
Probability of Missing both Bulls Eye and Inner Circle $P(M) = 0.4$
a) Probability of never stop shooting $P(N)$ = $1$-Probability of Hitting the target
$P(H)$.
$$P(H) = P(B)^2+P(I)P(B)+P(B)(I)+P(I)^2+P(M)P(B)^2+P(M)P(I)P(B)+P(M)P(B)P(I)+P(M)P(B)P(I)+P(M)P(I)^2+P(M)^2P(B)^2+P(M)^2P(B)P(I).........$$
$$P(H) = \{1+P(M)+P(M)^2+P(M)^3+P(M)^4....\}\times\{P(BB)+P(BI)+P(IB)+P(II)\}$$
$$P(H) = 1.6667 \times 0.36 $$
$$P(H) = 0.6$$
$$P(N) = 0.4$$
b) Probability she will stop shooting for having hit bullseye twice
$$\{1+P(M)+P(M)^2+P(M)^3+P(M)^4....\}\times\{P(BB)\}$$
$$=1.6667 \times 0.01$$
$$=0.01667$$
But answer in book is
a) $0$
b)$\dfrac{1}{36}$

She's shooting rounds of 2 arrows. So the probability of not finishing after a given round is not when she misses one shot (your $P(M)=0.4$), but when she misses at least one shot of the 2 shots. The probability for that is $1-0.6^2=0.64$, which mill make a) and b) correct.

Your approach for (a) is much too complicated.  Think more simply.  If the probability of hitting the inner ring is $\Pr[I] = 0.5$ and the bullseye $\Pr[B] = 0.1$, then the probability of missing either of these is $\Pr[M] = 1 - \Pr[I] - \Pr[B] = 0.4$.  Intuitively, for her to stop shooting, she would have to miss infinitely many times, because she will stop if she hits either the inner ring or bullseye on two separate attempts.  But the chance that she misses infinitely many times is $0$.  Put another way, the chance that she misses exactly $n$ times is $\Pr[M]^n = (0.4)^n$.  If we require her to miss infinitely many times, this event has probability $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (0.4)^n = 0.$$
For (b), this is simply
$$\frac{\Pr[BB]}{\Pr[BB] + \Pr[BI] + \Pr[IB] + \Pr[II]} = \frac{0.01}{0.01 + 0.05 + 0.05 + 0.25} = \frac{1}{36}$$ because we asked for a conditional probability:  given that she stops, what is the probability that she stops because she hit two bullseyes?
